# How parse xml using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I am new in JAXB, I want to read XML file to Java object, which is in the following format:

```xml
<payTypeList> 
    <payType>G</payType> 
    <payType>H</payType> 
    <payType>Y</payType> 
 </payTypeList>
```

Please help me how to read this type of XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is your scenario**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="payTypeList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PayTypeList {

    @XmlElement
    private List<String> payType;

    public List<String> getPayType() {
        return payType;
    }

    public void setPayType(List<String> payType) {
        this.payType = payType;
    }
}
```

**Method to use**

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
            final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PayTypeList.class);
            final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            final PayTypeList paymentType = new PayTypeList();

            List<String> paymentTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
            paymentTypes.add("one");
            paymentTypes.add("two");
            paymentTypes.add("three");
            paymentType.setPayType(paymentTypes);

            m.marshal(paymentType, System.out);
        }
```

**Output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<payTypeList>
    <payType>one</payType>
    <payType>two</payType>
    <payType>three</payType>
</payTypeList>
```

Comment: it was a pleasure to help you :) sign you issue as solved with accepted answer :)

Comment: @ArvindSingh this topis is still open?

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you will have a single class with a `List<String>` property.  The only annotations you may need to use are `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` to map the `List` property to the `payType` element.

**For More Information**

You can find more information about using these annotations on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Hi Doughan, Any helpful source code/link to configure Jaxb with MOXY.

Comment: @ArvindSingh - You can find lots of useful information on my blog:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/