# Generate a Stax Writer API for a given XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, stax

I have an XML Schema. I have written a thin layer over Stax to allow producing conforming documents 'on the fly' (I don't want a dom-like API, I need low/no footprint). The API has just methods like:

```
writeCar(String manufacturer)
writeWheels(String manufacturer, boolean winter)
...
```

These perform state checking and then call appropriate stax methods.

A specialty is that there are no writeEndXXX methods (My schema is unambigous, so you can't have any car inside a wheels element. This means I always know when to close open elements). The only exception is that there's a flush() which will write all pending end tags.

```
writeCar(..)   // <car>
writeWheels(..) // inside the car <wheels>
writeCar(..) // close the pending tags </wheels></car> and new car <car>
flush() // this writes all pending close tags
```

This works nicely. Now the schema evolves :)

I am now updating the API by hand. Because I'm virtuous, I don't want to do that really :). Is there a tool available that would generate such an API (or similar) given an XML Schema definition?

Comment: Have you either found or wrote any tool?

Comment: Neither of any.

Answer (score 0):

### JAXB Based

1. Generate an XSD from your XML. You can use also [this link](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html) or another tool works fine.
2. Generate classes from XSD by XJC, Maven plugin [see here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide)
3. Using any JAXB tutorial to perform marshal and unmarshal to read and write xml. [see here](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_3-Hello-World.html)

I suggest you also these link

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011446/jaxb-xsd-import-not-recognized/26011623#26011623)
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25266709/3364187)

I hope it can help you

Comment: This seems to be dom/object-graph based. Not what I need.